# How to change a powershell Invoke-RestMethod body from its original format into something else

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

I have a param section of a Invoke-RestMethod that i have to keep as is, but also add parameters:

```
$param = @{
...
Body = '{"entry":[{"@name":SOMETEXT,"static":{"member":[ANOTHERTEXT]}}]}' 
...
}
```

Since the entire `Body` is in single quotes, any `$parameter` added will be treated like a string instead of a normal PowerShell parameter

In this case `SOMETEXT` and `ANOTHERTEXT` will be `$HubAddressObject` and `$ArrayList`, respectivly.

How do i make that Body entry work with parameters, and keeping the same structure (this is part of a Panorama box)?

What i would need would be:

```
Body = '{"entry":[{"@name":$HubAddressObject,"static":{"member":[$ArrayList]}}]}'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know enough about what a “Panorama box” is to understand the constraints on PowerShell scripts, but would string concatenation work? E.g. ```Body = '{"entry":[{"@name":’ + $HubAddressObject + ‘,"static":{"member":[‘ + $ArrayList + ‘]}}]}'```. If you can link to relevant docs there might be other options..

Comment: You could do this by using double-quotes around the whole thing and escape the in-between double quotes with a backtick: ```"{`"entry`":[{`"@name`":$HubAddressObject,`"static`":{`"member`":[$ArrayList]}}]}"```, but wouldn't it be a lot easier if you have the data as **object** and convert that to JSON like with `$MyObject | ConvertTo-Json -Compress` ??

Comment: @mclayton - gave me the idea to rework this a bit, resulting in: `('{{"entry":[{{"@name": "{0}","static": {{"member": [{1}]}}}}]}}' -F 'SOMETEXT', 'ANOTHERTEXT')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `ConvertFrom-Json` / `ConvertTo-Json` for that kind of thing.

To keep it one 1 line, you can use the `-Compress` switch.

```
$params = @{
  Body = '{"entry":[{"@name":"SOMETEXT","static":{"member":"[ANOTHERTEXT]"}}]}' 
}

# Create a PSObject representation of your JSON
$jsonObj = $Params.body | ConvertFrom-Json

#Modify whatever you want
$jsonObj.entry[0].'@name' = 'NewText'

# Convert the Object back to Json.
$Params.Body = $JsonObj | Convertto-Json -Compress -Depth 4
```

Json comparison

```
# Starting off Json
{"entry":[{"@name":"SOMETEXT","static":{"member":"[ANOTHERTEXT]"}}]}
# Modified JSON
{"entry":[{"@name":"NewText","static":{"member":"[ANOTHERTEXT]"}}]}
```

Comment: This also works, tested with my own parameters i have prepared. I tried something similar initially, but this is more complex than i would've thought.
Thanks.

Comment: This is better than building the json string yourself - it properly escapes characters like ```{``` and ```}``` in the variable values, which would at best cause an exception, and at worst could expose a json-injection vulnerability…